# how to load this jquery before page loads

Tags: jquery

How can I change this to instead of changing when in mouse over, I want the code to replace the following input before page loads.

```js
  $("#fieldsample").mouseover(
    function() {
      $("#input_12_1").val(jQuery(this).val().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ""))
    }
  );

});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="<DT></DT><DD>content</DD>" id="fieldsample" name="lname">
```

Comment: Your snippet is giving a script error. Also, your HTML is invalid

Answer (score 0):

change your jslike below

```
$("#fieldsample").mouseover(function () {
  var val = jQuery(this).val().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");
  $("#input_12_1").val(val);
});
```

```js
$("#fieldsample").mouseover(function () {
  var value = jQuery(this).val().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");
  $("#input_12_1").val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="<DT></DT><DD>content</DD>" id="fieldsample" name="lname"/>

<input type="text" value="" id="input_12_1"/>
```